# Registering Wii U Download Code

Tags: wii-u

So, a friend and I have both bought Mario Kart 8, and have thus been able to choose a free game to go with it. We have now received the download codes, however, my friend has a problem.

The codes expire before next month, and he doesn't have enough space to download his free game at the moment.

I've suggested he does the following:

- Delete Mario 3D World from his system, in order to make space. (not touching his save file of course)
- Download his free game onto the system.
- Delete it from his system.
- Download Mario 3D World back onto his system.

As far as I know, doing this would register the free game as downloaded on his account, and he'll be able to download it again any time in the future.

Is this correct, or have I missed or misunderstood something?
Are there any better ways to do this?

PS: We know he could just get more space for his system, but that is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Is there no way to acquire the game without instantly downloading it?

Comment: I don't know. If there is, I sure would like to know. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done this myself but I know others who did the same. Indeed, if you make space on your internal memory so you're able to download the game, you'll be able to download it again in the future.

(Unless you delete your Nintendo Network account or the user from your system).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a WiiU, but on the Wii and 3DS, you can purchase things from the store and then simply choose not to download it.

The way the system works is that you're charged for the item before downloading begins, so once the purchase goes through, you can simply hit the Home button to head back to the system menu.

Incidentally, if you do choose to upgrade to higher capacity in the future, bear in mind that WiiU programs can only use USB Drives (either HDDs or Flash?) and the Wii compatibility mode can only use SD (or SDHC, **not** SDXC) cards.

Comment: But the thing is, this free game campaign thing, does not work in entirely the same way. We don't "buy" the free game, but go into the eShop and activate a code we've been e-mailed. I didn't pay much attention when I did it myself, but afaik, when activating, the download has to start right away. It therefore seems that there's no way to actually register the free game as "purchased" until it's actually been download, in this case. (I might be wrong about this though, but this is how I perceive it at least.)